# Jersey XML indentation

Tags: java, jaxb2, jersey-2.0

I have the following code:

```
@Path("/search")
public class SearchRestlet
        extends BaseRestlet
{

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    public SearchResult search(...)
            throws IOException, ParseException
    {
        final SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(...);
        final SearchResult result = searchService.search(searchRequest);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Here's my `JAXB` mapped object:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "result")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SearchResult
{

    @XmlElement
    private String id;

    ...

}
```

This is the output I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><result><id>foo</id></result>
```

This is the output I'd like to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<result>
    <id>foo</id>
</result>
```

If I were using a marshaller directly, I know I can set a property for this and that it should work. How can this be done from within the context of Jersey based on the example above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to your `web.xml` deployment descriptor:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.xml.formatOutput</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

For more details, check [`MessageProperties.XML_FORMAT_OUTPUT`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/message/MessageProperties.html#XML_FORMAT_OUTPUT).